# in grpah what will be the fastest way to find all the nodes connected to one node but not connected to another node.?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Say you have two nodes P and Q. Now we have to find the nodes having edge with Q but not with P. What is the fastest way to do this? What algorithm or data structure should I use? Currently whenever adding an edge I am maintaining a vector with each node which saves all the nodes connected to that node (Lets call this Vi for ith node). Also I am having adjacency matrix. Roughly something like this I am doing.

`for each node in Vq

         check if it is connected to P using adjacency matrix

          do something with this node`

Do you think anything faster can be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same thing:

- Take the P row and the Q row from the adjacency matrix
- For node I,

  - if the I'th column has a 0 in the P row and a 1 in the Q row, do operation.

This is being explicit about not having another loop inside the for loop for "checking if it is connected".

That's the fastest you can do theoretically (this is O(n) and the theoretical lowerbound is O(n)). In practice, you might be able to optimize it depending on what language you're using and what it's optimized to do. For example Matlab would love it if you phrased it as:

```
nodes = (~rowP)*rowQ';
```

Comment: I was also thinking on similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it should run no faster than linear time.  Every node must be checked, but the existence of an edge is verified in constant time.